how to use gnuplot with one x and several y
i need to make a plot from the file that have struct like that:
x1, y1, y2, y3, y4
x2, y1, y2, y3, y4
x3, y1, y2, y3, y4
I am tried something like
set datafile separator ','
but with that he make plot with only x1 and y1

What kind of plot? What's wrong with plot 'file.dat' using 1:2, '' using 1:3, '' using 1:4, '' using 1:5?

oh, at first i dont recognize how using a:b works
thank you!

If the number of columns stays the same, you can tell gnuplot which columns to use:
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2, '' using 1:3, '' using 1:4, '' using 1:5

